# Javascript: Remove Hyphen from HTML5 Geolocation Longitude

Tags: javascript

I am using the snipper bellow to remove first dash/hyphen that prepends the longitude number, but it does not work:

```
 let lng = (position.coords.longitude);
  lng = lng.replace(/-/g, ' ');
  console.log(pks);
```

I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: lng.replace is not a function
    at ...
```

Comment: `lng.toString().replace` maybe?

Comment: or `Math.abs(lng)`

Comment: `lng` is a number, not a string. Use mathematical operations on it. But I can't understand why you would want to do this -- the sign of the longitude is important. If you remove it, you're moving the location to the opposite side of the Atlantic.